# Find immediate less value from object or map using JS

Tags: javascript

```
object -> let error = {3:1, 4:1, 10:2, 12:1, 13:2} or {3:1, 4:1, 12:1, 13:2}
map ->  let map = new Map([[3,1],[4,1],[10,2],[12,1],[13,2]]}
```

if my number is 10 means I need to get the value of 4 ie immediate less and if no less value then I need to return largest value.

for now, I will decrement the value and check if the exists in the map and return the value. Currently, I am using an object. If the passed number exists or not need to find immediate less value.

my obj contains 1, 3, 7, 10 is my keys and 5 is the number passed and I need to find the immediate less value 3 < 5 . if value passed 7 also 3<7. it is not based on index. its based on keys.

```
myFunction = (number) => {
    let index; 
    for(int i = number; i>=number ; i--){
      if(error[i] != undefined){
          index = i;
          break;
      }
    }
return index;
}
```

Is there any better way to do the same ?

Comment: What do you mean by immediate less, will always be one at the index lower than occurrence of value ?

Comment: No . Its not imediate lower index. I need to find the value of the index lesser. ex my obj contains 1, 3, 7, 10 is my keys and 5 is the number passed and I need to find the immediate less value 3 < 5 . if  value passed 7 also 3<7. Not based on index based on key value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the values in descending order and then use find the first value which is less than number, if the value is found return that value else return the last value

```js
let mapper = [[3,1],[4,1],[10,2],[12,1],[13,2]].sort((a,b)=>b[0]-a[0])

let myFunction = (number) => {
  let value = mapper.find((v, i) => {
    if (v[0] < number) {
      return v[1]
    }
  })
  return value  || mapper[0]
}

console.log(myFunction(10))
console.log(myFunction(9))
console.log(myFunction(2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the number directly and decrement the value until it reaches zero.

```js
function fn(number) {
   while (number--) if (number in error) return number;
}

var error = { 3: 1, 4: 1, 10: 2, 12: 1, 13: 2 };

console.log(fn(9));
console.log(fn(10));
```

Comment: ***On side note:-*** clever, but this can lead you to infinite loop if any value less than the minimum value is passed as number, or have to loop a lot if there a very big number wrt to max value present in object